# SQL Server INSERT results from OUTPUT into an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a transaction that deletes records from several tables. I would like to store a record of each deletion inside of a different table called **DeleteLog**.

My transaction:

```
-- SET THESE VARS TO CLIENT INFO
DECLARE @OrganizationID INT = 25
DECLARE @AreaID INT = 1181
DECLARE @ExpID INT = 43926

BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
  BEGIN TRY

    -- EXP HISTORY.
    DELETE [ExpHistory] OUTPUT DELETED.*
    FROM [ExpHistory] 
    INNER JOIN [Area] ON [ExpHistory].AreaID = [Area].ID
    INNER JOIN [Organization] ON [Area].OrganizationID = [Organization].ID
    INNER JOIN [Exp] ON [ExpHistory].ExpID = [Exp].ID
    WHERE [ExpHistory].AreaID = @AreaID AND [Organization].ID = @OrganizationID AND [Exp].ID = 
    @ExpID

    -- INSERT OUTPUT INTO EXISTING TABLE CALLED DeleteLog

    -- EXP.
    DELETE [Exp] OUTPUT DELETED.*
    FROM [Exp] 
    INNER JOIN [Area] ON [Exp].AreaID = [Area].ID
    INNER JOIN [Organization] ON [Area].OrganizationID = [Organization].ID
    WHERE [Exp].AreaID = @AreaID AND [Organization].ID = @OrganizationID AND [Exp].ID = @ExpID

    -- INSERT OUTPUT INTO EXISTING TABLE CALLED DeleteLog

  COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]

END CATCH
```

The output clause returns the deleted items as expected, but now I would like to insert them into my **DeleteLog** table. I will need to set specific columns so I don't believe that using INTO will work. I have seen MERGE as a potential solution.

Comment: Check this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-insert-and-delete-statements

Comment: The logic here doesn't make sense to me. Do all of these tables have identical schemas? If not, what does this `DeleteLog` table look like? Why not just use temporal tables and let the server do the work for you?

Comment: Or why not use a trigger to populate your DeleteLog table?